# How to find the context of CustomDialog

Tags: android

I've one custom dialog box

```
customDialog = new CustomizeDialog(this);
customDialog.setContentView(R.layout.student_register_form);
```

Here is one popupwindow declared like this

```
ListViewPopupWindow countryPopupWindow = new
ListViewPopupWindow(this,R.layout.grade_popup_layout, values, Ids, "country");
```

Here is Implementaion

```
public ListViewPopupWindow(Context ctx,int popup_layout,ArrayList<String> values,
ArrayList<String> ids,String tag){
```

My problem is I'm not able to find the context

Comment: what does "I'm not able to find the context" mean?

Comment: Same question like blackbelt...

Comment: what context you want???

Comment: Thanq for attempted,in my implementation of popupwindow,1st parameter is Context,so I got confusion.

Comment: where do you want to pass context? For ListViewPopupWindow or CustomizeDialog?

Comment: main activity name : Login.java

Comment: @PiyushGupta,ListViewPopupWindow only,my entire code is designed at there,so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Inflate popupview
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(
                LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
       View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.grade_popup_layout,
                null);
```

use this popupView as your context.

Comment: this is ok,how to pass the Context to where I implemented the metho